# Ubuntu 18.04 auto setup image

Tags: 18.04, server, preseed, disk-image

I'm trying to work out how to make an ISO image for a Ubuntu 18.04 that I can use to install on a remote server from OVH.

Using there BYOI system if I can use an image thats been preseed with the SSH, root password etc I can set it to install unattented then login via SSH and continue with any updates, additional software etc.

Can anyone help? point me to an easy to follow guide as its something I've never done and do not wish to make a mess, lol...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Two questions: Why 18.04 - which will be EOL in one year, and why not installing an Ubuntu server iso 1:1 ,configure it and  build an iso like described [here](https://linuxhint.com/create-iso-current-installation-ubuntu/) ?

Comment: I have some scripts and code that wont work on newer ubuntu's, so it has to be 18.04